# Can I create a new world in Don't Starve without losing my progress?

Tags: dont-starve

As far as I have seen, progress in Don't Starve is saved in the form of research points, researched crafting recipes and unlocked characters. I'm afraid to click the "Make New World" button in case it clears that long term progress. Does anybody know if it will?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This question is now obsolete, as the game now has four save slots (and no Make New World button anymore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll keep your acquired recipes and science points, and all your unlocked characters.

Clicking Make New World is actually almost exactly the same as dying, only when you start again the world will look different.

Comment: @Codemonkey To clarify what Eric B said, "Make New World" randomly generates a new map.